# Filtering with polars in Rust - Eagerly

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I'm trying to do a simple filter with polars in rust :

```
let mask = df.column("AISLE_ID").unwrap().eq(lit(1));
let filtered_df = df.filter(&mask).unwrap();
```

But it's not working at all : expected `&ChunkedArray<...>`, found `&bool`

I can do it with lazy way but I don't want to clone dataframe

```
let dfe = df.clone();
    let filtered_df = dfe.lazy().filter(
        col("AISLE_ID").eq(lit(1))
    )
    .collect();
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: Why do you need the clone?

Comment: You're implicitly cloning in the first example because `df.filter` returns a brand new DataFrame.

Comment: I need to clone it because if don't do it, I have an error "doesn't have trait copy".
A way to do it without cloning ?

Comment: can you post your import ?  "use ..." . or else, I guess your code use 'dfe' after filtered_df with filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned by others, whenever you do a `filter`, whether it's lazy or not, a copy of the data is performed as a new DataFrame is created. The difference is **when** the copy is performed (along with optimizations if multiple transformations happen in the scope of the lazy DataFrame).

In your original lazy example, the initial `let def = df.copy()` is not necessary. The following code compiles and works as expected:

```
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let s0 = Series::new("AISLE_ID", [0, 1, 2].as_ref());
    let s1 = Series::new("temp", [22.1, 19.9, 7.].as_ref());
    let df = DataFrame::new(vec![s0, s1]).unwrap();
    let filtered_df = df.lazy().filter(
        col("AISLE_ID").eq(lit(1))
    )
    .collect();

    println!("{:?}", filtered_df)
}
```

Returning:

```
Ok(shape: (1, 2)
┌──────────┬──────┐
│ AISLE_ID ┆ temp │
│ ---      ┆ ---  │
│ i32      ┆ f64  │
╞══════════╪══════╡
│ 1        ┆ 19.9 │
└──────────┴──────┘)
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
polars = { version = "0.29.0", features = ["lazy"] }
```